# Is there a durable queue library for the JVM?

Tags: architecture, asynchronous, queue, message-queue

I'm looking for the functionality of a BlockingQueue that queues to disk instead of memory. I'd rather avoid a heavyweight solution (e.g. JMS). Ideally the queue should run in the same process as the client (producer) and consumer, on the JVM. It should be able to continue queuing if the consumer is stopped, and also survive restarts.

Comment: What about hacking that on-top of a relational table? That approach has some advantages.

Comment: That's tempting but I've read a few articles on the queue-as-database being an anti-pattern, so I'm a bit skittish on pursuing that approach. I've seen a few solutions that use berkley db (java edition)

Answer (score 1):

What about hacking that on-top of a relational table? That approach has some advantages.

It might be an anti-pattern and sometimes it is. There are pitfalls (especially that contention might be high without special care).

But there are meaningful advantages as well: You can integrate the queue data with other data, you get ACID semantics, you get consistent backups (which you don't get with any external queue because you can't backup it at the exact same time as the DB) and you save using a new technology in your project.

Assign each queue item a status and index on it.

Here is a simple contention management technique: Add a random number to each queue row. When dequeueing, ask for `select TOP 1 * from QueueTable where RandomNumberColumn > RAND() order by RandomNumberColumn`. That gives you an item taken from a random position, giving you a great reduction in blocking due to X-locking.

Comment: I decided to use Berkeley DB (Java). It's embedded and the low level api seems to be well suited for a queue impl.